# Access the contents of packed resource dictionary in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, pack, app.xaml

How can I access and view the contents of a resource from a third-party library in WPF?

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/XXX;component/Styles/Components.xaml" />
```

Comment: Not enough information, how exactly do you want to access it? And where does that line of code that you've pasted appear in your project? If it's in your App.xaml then just give it an x:Name and you can then access it as you would any other global resource.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Hi Mark, I want to see what is inside Components.xaml

Comment: Again, you need to provide more information. If you want to see what's inside components.xaml then what's stopping you from simply opening up components.xaml in the text editor and simply looking at the code?

Comment: @MarkFeldman Hi again! How can I open it? Where is it located? The above code is inside App.xaml and Component.xaml is inside a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is compiled into BAML so if you have a compiled third-party assembly, you'll need a decompiler that can decompile BAML to XAML. An example of such a decompiler is [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

If you download it (it's free of charge) and open the XXX assembly in it, you should be able to see the XAML markup of `Styles/Components.xaml` if you look for `components.baml` in the tree view in the assemmbly explorer.

Please refer to JetBrain's web site for more information about how to use dotPeek: https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/features/